# Visual FoxPro data in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, oledb, visual-foxpro

We are in the process of migrating an old VFP application into a .NET WPF application with SQL server.
During the process we still need to read/write to the DBF files to keep our business working properly.

To do this, we use the standard OLEDB adapter that is available. However, our sysadmin is asking if we have an alternative way to access the DBF files.
Having each user connect to the files is not the best option from a network/security perspective. Specially when connecting from home through a VPN.

I've already tried to move the connection to a single server by exposing the data through an API. But that was slowing down the application too much. In some situations we synchronise the data through background jobs (Hangfire implementation). But this can be time consuming to implement.

Has anybody used any other techniques to do something similar while migrating a VFP application?

Answer (score 2):

OLEDB is still the best option. Within the application, you could impersonate a specific user that has access to files.
Also Sybase Advantage Server can connect and work with VFP data files. Local mode is (was) for free and server mode paid. You might try checking that too.

Comment: Sybase has been bought by SAP a few years back. So I would be surprised if there is still a free version. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Locate data on single PC as server. Access via RDP - kludges available to support multiple connections. Increase security if needed by connecting over VPN - then RDP.